# Knowing Which Button Was pressed! GTK

Tags: arrays, button, gtk

I'm making a board like this

```
GtkWidget *board[x][y];
```

If I do an array of buttons, how can I know which button was pressed?

Does

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(board[][]), "clicked",  
       G_CALLBACK(board_button_pressed), NULL);
// I want to know what [][] they pressed, how could I verify/check this?
```

return which button of the array was pressed? Or do I have to make a separate function for each of the board pieces?

For example:

```
OOO
OXO
OOO
```

How to know which button was pressed if all of the buttons are named the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest way would be to just send the information when you are connecting to the callback as data. Something on these lines:

```
...

typedef struct _identifier{
    int x;
    int y;
}identifier;

static void button_clicked_cb(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button; /*To get rid of compiler warning*/
    identifier *id = data;
    printf("\n id = %d, %d\n", id->x, id->y);
    return;
}
....
    identifier id[x*y]; /* Size of x*y of the board*/
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            id[counter].x = i;
            id[counter].y = j;
            board[i][j] = gtk_button_new ();
            g_signal_connect(board[i][j], "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked_cb), &id[counter]);
            counter++;
        }                                                                                                                                                     
    }
```

Please note that `"clicked"` signal is associated only with `GtkButton`. If you need to use with `GtkWidget` then look at `"button-press-event"` or `"button-release-event"`, in which case the callback signature will also change.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Give me a sec and Im going to try it and see what happens, thanks for the help!

Comment: I seee identifier *id=data; what does "data" stands for?

Comment: `data` is parameter passed to the callback function. You can set what data is to be passed when you connecting it using `g_signal_connect`